# Convert BufferedImage to Image data type

Tags: java, mysql, imageview, blob, bufferedimage

I am trying to retrieve blob data type from database table and display the image in a imageView. Here is my select SQL statement:

```
public boolean retrieve(){
boolean success = false;
ResultSet rs = null;
DBController db = new DBController();   
db.getConnection();     
String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM sm_product WHERE productName ='" + name +"'";       
rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);
try {
    if(rs.next()){
        desc = rs.getString("productDescription");
        price = rs.getInt("productPrice");
        quantity = rs.getInt("productQuantity");
        dateStr = rs.getString("dateOfCreation");
                    category = rs.getString("productCategory");     

                   Blob blob = rs.getBlob("productImage");
                   byte[] data = blob.getBytes(0, (int) blob.length());
                   image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data)); //Error here
                    success = true;
    }   
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}   
db.terminate();
return success;
}
```

After retrieved, I want to display it in a imageview. Here is the code:

```
panel.getMyImageView().setImage(product.getImage());
```

However, I got incompatible type error message. I know image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data)); this line supposed to store as BufferedImage and then from there I slowly convert to image datatype and display in image view. But after 2 hours of researching, I got no luck. Can somebody please help me with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(data)
```

Call this for the byte array read from the blob